# Maintain sql order in mysql after group

Tags: sql, mysql

I have next sql

```
select site_id,count from tags where match (tag) against ('statistici' in boolean mode) ORDER BY count DESC;

+---------+-------+
| site_id | count |
+---------+-------+
|       9 |  1300 |
|      13 |  1200 |
|       9 |  1100 |
|      13 |  1000 |
|       9 |   900 |
|      13 |   800 |
|      13 |   800 |
+---------+-------+
```

What i need is to get distinct site_id.
But when i use a group by statement the order by count is not kept

```
select site_id,count from tags where match (tag) against ('statistici' in boolean mode) GROUP by site_id ORDER BY count DESC;

+---------+-------+
| site_id | count |
+---------+-------+
|      13 |  1000 |
|       9 |   900 |
+---------+-------+
```

What should i do ?

Comment: My solution will be SELECT site_id FROM (select site_id,count from tags t where match (tag) against ('statistici' in boolean mode) ORDER BY count DESC) s GROUP by s.site_id; but i have no ideea if this is optimized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ordering by `ORDER BY count DESC`, and the result is ordered with the highest count first.

Change to `ORDER BY count ACS` if you prefer the lowest count first.

EDIT:  Based on your comment, perhaps this is more like what you're trying to achieve:

```
select  site_id
,       max(count) as TopCount
from    tags 
where   match (tag) against ('statistici' in boolean mode) 
group by 
        site_id 
order by
        TopCount DESC
```

This selects the highest count per site, and places the highest count first.

Comment: I need to be ordered by highest to lowest. As you see there is site_id with 9 and count 1300 so the second statement should show that first.

Answer (score 0):

Group by site_Id order by count(*);